# Get the actual state of a bitmap

Tags: sql

Here is the problem:
The orders are represented by a from and to dates and 2 bitmask fileds.
One is representing the ordered dates between FromDate and ToDate, the second representing the data if the order is valid for the given date
There might be modifications to that order which are represented by a subset of the original FromDate and ToDate and the bitmask fields.
The trick is that when a modifications comes only a part of a bitmask is sent back

```
create table orders
(
ref_id int,
DateFrom datetime,
DateTo datetime,
version int,
DateBitmask varchar(255),
DataBitmask varchar(255)
)
```

Sample data:

```
ref_id DateFrom DateTo   Version DateBitmap DataBitmap
1      20150801 20150810 0       0011101110 0000101100
1      20150810 20150810 1                1          1
1      20150803 20150804 2                    11      
1      20150810 20150810 3                1          0
```

The result I'm looking for is a kind of historical "running sum" of the Databitmap field to finally get he latest actual state of the DataBitmap.
Actually the only way we have found to achieve this to go trough the whole database and check for all the ref_id all the modifications, update a temp value for that ref_id and finally and get the end result.

To give you a hint the end result for the given example would be `0011101100`

because the initial data was `0000101100`

This was first modified for the last position which gave us `0000101101`

Than it was modified for the 2nd and 3rd position which gave us `0011101101`

After all that was modified again for the last position which gave us `0011101100`

How can I achieve this in a fast and elegant manner?
The table hosting those data is rather big (50-60 Mio records) and gets bigger.

And before somebody is suggesting us to change the table structure, unfortunately we can't.

Any idea?

Comment: Which dbms product are you using?

Comment: @Gabor not one can help you if you don't answer jarlh's question as I also need that info

Comment: Actually it is in Oracle. But if you have a solution for SQLServer or MySql that's fine for me to :-) That's why I didn't specified the rdbms

Comment: @Gabor are you interested in all of the changes or just the end result ?

Comment: But the result is a kind of sequential running sum of each versions. (we are doing this with substring updates, but this is too slow).

Comment: @Gabor ok, I MAY be getting to an answer, but I need 2 answers. 1. Can you have in the save time 1 and 0 ? for example `  1 010   1` . 2. The answer for the first DateBitmap column is `0011110000` ?

Comment: There is no `DateTime` data type in Oracle.

Comment: I know. I've made this example out of SQLServer. Again: an rdbms solution would be fine

Comment: @cosmin: Well this is tricky. To have your life easier, you can forget the DateBitmap. That one indicates whether we hate to take into account the corresponding data within the DataBitmap. So if we hae a 0 in a specific position in DateBitmap, we are disregarding the value in DataBitmap

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I will try to cover it and hopefully is good enough or at least it helps you.

So, you need to make some replacements and simple operations and use bitwise operators since you have that structure. We will convert the binary values to decimals, operate on them then convert them back in binary. A application on your example would be :

```
SELECT BIN(CONV(BINARY('0000101100'), 2, 10) + CONV(BINARY('0000000001'), 2, 10) + CONV(BINARY('0011000000'), 2, 10) + CONV(BINARY('1111111110'), 2, 10) - 1023);
```

So, as you can see I have just made a sum on your info from the `DataBitmap` and replaced the blank spaces with 0. IF you have a 0 in your `DataBitmap` we must replace the blank spaces with 1 and then substract 1023 (2^10 - 1). And of course you can eliminate the 0 left of the first 1, so that would make us :

```
SELECT BIN(CONV(BINARY('101100'), 2, 10) + CONV(BINARY('1'), 2, 10) + CONV(BINARY('11000000'), 2, 10) + CONV(BINARY('1111111110'), 2, 10) - 1023);
```

The result of this in MySQL is `11101100` witch is also your result, without the first 2 `0`.

In case you also have 1 and 0 on the same line you need to split that line in one line with only 0 and one line with only 1 and apply 2 opperations on it.

For example, if you had :

```
ref_id DateFrom DateTo   Version DateBitmap DataBitmap
1      20150801 20150810 0       0011101110 0000101100
1      20150810 20150810 1                1        011
```

That should be translated in :

```
ref_id DateFrom DateTo   Version DateBitmap DataBitmap
1      20150801 20150810 0       0011101110 0000101100
1      20150810 20150810 1                1         11
1      20150810 20150810 1                1        0
```

And then we can make :

```
SELECT BIN(CONV(BINARY('0000101100'), 2, 10) + CONV(BINARY('11'), 2, 10) + CONV(BINARY('1111111011'), 2, 10) - 1023);
```

Witch will give back `101011`

Comment: Well, this is a bit tricky. 0 in the DataBitmap means NO. So if you replace the empty value by 0 that would mean that you are setting everything to NO which is not desired